# Performing DELETE call in DRF using axios returns 301

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm struggling with calling delete on my drf api using axios. Constantly returns 301... I'm having one class based view containing create/list/delete methods. What might be wrong here?

axios call:

```
async delete_qr(id){
        api.delete("tickets/qr/delete/"+String(id), {headers:{Authorization:'JWT '+this.$store.state.jwt}, data:{pk:id}})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.tickets = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

views.py

```
class TicketApi(CreateAPIView, ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAdminUser,
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = TicketSerializer
    queryset = Tickets.objects.all()

    def destroy(self, request, pk):
        ticket = self.get_object(pk)
        self.perform_destroy(ticket)
        return Response({"info":f"ticket with id {pk} has been deleted"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

urls.py

```
# path('tickets/', include("tickets.urls")) -> from main.urls
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("qr/create", TicketApi, basename="qr_create")
router.register("qr/list", TicketApi, basename="qr_list")
router.register("qr/delete", TicketApi, basename="qr_delete")
```

Comment: Well, for one you don't appear to have a URL of `tickets/qr/delete/` in your urls.py. For another, you shouldn't specify the ACTION in your URL. Use the resource URL and the different HTTP action to route it to the correct method.

Comment: tickets/.. redirects to concrete app.urls. It works fine.